# Moving from one directory to another java

Tags: java

This is my code. Basically, I want to filter the filenames and move it in the same folder

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file = new File(path);
    String[] content = file.list();
     FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
                         if (lowercaseName.startsWith("to1.")){
                              File d = new File("TO1");
                              d.mkdir();
```

I wanted to move all the files with the prefix with `TO1.` into the same folder
somehow I don't know how to implement the move in java. what can you guys recommend?

Comment: That doesn't look like all of the code.

Comment: i've checked that out but, is it posible to use that under the filter?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Tip: Add @VincentRayBermejo (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Bear in mind that you probably have more options for doing this in Java 8 and newer thanks to `Path.find`, streams, and lambdas.

Comment: Sorry, `java.nio.files`'s `Files.find` . Lost track of which one has static methods in it.